# IF condition containing IN operator inside ORACLE Trigger is not working

Tags: sql, oracle, if-statement, triggers, in-operator

I have a trigger that uses `IF` condition with `IN` operator and two variables `v_audit_user` and `v_evdnse_user` inside IN. Both variables are containing comma separated ID values. The trigger gets compiled successfully with no errors. I am not understanding why the `IF` condition with `IN` is not working. When I select the function that assigns value to the variables independently, I do see the comma separated values, so nothing is wrong with function (see screenshot).

[image: Coomma Separated Values]

```
create or replace TRIGGER TRG_CHK_HRCQA_CASE_ACTIONS
AFTER INSERT ON KDD_CASE_ACTIONS
FOR EACH ROW
DECLARE

 user_audit kdd_review_owner.OWNER_ID%TYPE; /* The user that is displayed in audit */
 user_evdnse kdd_review_owner.OWNER_ID%TYPE; /* The user that took action in evidence tab */
 v_audit_user NUMBER;  /* The HRCO/QA user from audit tab */
 v_evdnse_user NUMBER; /* The HRCO/QA user from evidence tab */
 LV_ERRORCODE VARCHAR2(1000);

BEGIN

  /* pass the username into the variables */

    SELECT kro.OWNER_ID into user_audit from kdd_review_owner kro where kro.OWNER_SEQ_ID = :NEW.ACTION_BY_ID;

    SELECT kro.OWNER_ID into user_evdnse from kdd_review_owner kro where kro.OWNER_SEQ_ID = :NEW.ACTION_BY_ID;

  /* fetch the comma separated IDs */
  
   v_audit_user := F_GET_HRCQA_ACTIONS(:NEW.CASE_INTRL_ID,user_audit,'AUDIT');

   v_evdnse_user := F_GET_HRCQA_ACTIONS(:NEW.CASE_INTRL_ID,user_evdnse,'EVDNSE');


  --  select ENTITY_ID into v_evdnse_user from table(f_get_arg_table(F_GET_HRCQA_ACTIONS(:NEW.CASE_INTRL_ID,user_evdnse,'EVDNSE')));
  /* If the action taken is by QA or HRCO role */

    IF (:NEW.ACTION_SEQ_ID in (v_audit_user,v_evdnse_user)) 

    THEN

  /* then insert record in the SC_HRCQA_CASE_ACTIONS table with IS_HRCO_QA flag as Y  */

        Insert into SC_HRCQA_CASE_ACTIONS (ACTION_SEQ_ID,ACTION_BY_ID,ACTION_TS,STATUS_CD,CASE_INTRL_ID,ACTION_ID,NEW_CASE_OWNR_ASSGN_ID,CASE_DUE_TS,PREV_CASE_OWNR_ASSGN_ID,IS_HRCO_QA) 
        values (:NEW.ACTION_SEQ_ID, :NEW.ACTION_BY_ID, :NEW.ACTION_TS, :NEW.STATUS_CD, :NEW.CASE_INTRL_ID, :NEW.ACTION_ID, :NEW.NEW_CASE_OWNR_ASSGN_ID, :NEW.CASE_DUE_TS, :NEW.PREV_CASE_OWNR_ASSGN_ID,'Y');

--        ELSE
--
--  /* else the logged in user is NOT HRCO/QA hence insert record in the SC_HRCQA_CASE_ACTIONS table with IS_HRCO_QA flag as N  */   
--
--        Insert into SC_HRCQA_CASE_ACTIONS (ACTION_SEQ_ID,ACTION_BY_ID,ACTION_TS,STATUS_CD,CASE_INTRL_ID,ACTION_ID,NEW_CASE_OWNR_ASSGN_ID,CASE_DUE_TS,PREV_CASE_OWNR_ASSGN_ID,IS_HRCO_QA) 
--        values (:NEW.ACTION_SEQ_ID, :NEW.ACTION_BY_ID, :NEW.ACTION_TS, :NEW.STATUS_CD, :NEW.CASE_INTRL_ID, :NEW.ACTION_ID, :NEW.NEW_CASE_OWNR_ASSGN_ID, :NEW.CASE_DUE_TS, :NEW.PREV_CASE_OWNR_ASSGN_ID,'N');

    END IF;

EXCEPTION
    WHEN OTHERS THEN LV_ERRORCODE := SQLCODE;
        INSERT INTO KDD_LOGS_MSGS (LOG_DT, LOG_INFO_TX, REMARK_TX)
        VALUES (SYSDATE,'ErrorCode - ' || LV_ERRORCODE,'TRG_CHK_HRCQA_CASE_ACTIONS');
END;
```

Comment: Whenever you have a question, please post a little sample data (CREATE TABLE and INSERT statements for all tables involved, relevant columns only) so the people who want to help you can re-create the problem and test their ideas. Also post the exact results you want from that data, and explain why you want those results from that data. Always post your complete Oracle version (e.g. 18.4.0.0.0). In addition, don't post images as they cant be cut and pasted

Comment: Sure @Pugzly I will add sample data and other requested info in the morning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot pass a comma-delimited string stored in a single variable to an `IN` condition and expect it to be parsed as multiple values as it is not.

If you want to use a single variable containing a delimited list then you will need to use string functions to find a sub-string match:

```sql
create or replace TRIGGER TRG_CHK_HRCQA_CASE_ACTIONS
  AFTER INSERT ON KDD_CASE_ACTIONS
  FOR EACH ROW
DECLARE
  v_owner_id    kdd_review_owner.OWNER_ID%TYPE;
  v_audit_user  VARCHAR2(1000);
  v_evdnse_user VARCHAR2(1000);
  LV_ERRORCODE  VARCHAR2(1000);
BEGIN
  SELECT OWNER_ID
  into   v_owner_id                         -- You only need one variable here
  from   kdd_review_owner
  where  OWNER_SEQ_ID = :NEW.ACTION_BY_ID;

  v_audit_user := F_GET_HRCQA_ACTIONS(:NEW.CASE_INTRL_ID, v_owner_id, 'AUDIT');
  v_evdnse_user := F_GET_HRCQA_ACTIONS(:NEW.CASE_INTRL_ID, v_owner_id, 'EVDNSE');

  IF ','||v_audit_user||','||v_evdnse_user||',' LIKE '%,'||:NEW.ACTION_SEQ_ID||',%'
  THEN
     Insert into SC_HRCQA_CASE_ACTIONS (
       ACTION_SEQ_ID, ACTION_BY_ID, ACTION_TS, STATUS_CD, CASE_INTRL_ID,
       ACTION_ID, NEW_CASE_OWNR_ASSGN_ID, CASE_DUE_TS, PREV_CASE_OWNR_ASSGN_ID, IS_HRCO_QA
     ) values (
       :NEW.ACTION_SEQ_ID, :NEW.ACTION_BY_ID, :NEW.ACTION_TS, :NEW.STATUS_CD, :NEW.CASE_INTRL_ID,
       :NEW.ACTION_ID, :NEW.NEW_CASE_OWNR_ASSGN_ID, :NEW.CASE_DUE_TS, :NEW.PREV_CASE_OWNR_ASSGN_ID,'Y'
     );
  END IF;
EXCEPTION
    WHEN OTHERS THEN LV_ERRORCODE := SQLCODE;
        INSERT INTO KDD_LOGS_MSGS (LOG_DT, LOG_INFO_TX, REMARK_TX)
        VALUES (SYSDATE,'ErrorCode - ' || LV_ERRORCODE,'TRG_CHK_HRCQA_CASE_ACTIONS');
END;
/
```

Comment: Does this also take care of the first value returned in the string which has no preceding comma? I am asking because your IF starts with comma.

Comment: Also, do you think the function  F_GET_HRCQA_ACTIONS will get called and assign the comma separated string to v_audit_user and v_evdnse_user the way it has been written? Is it the correct syntax to call and assign the value?

Comment: @ReeyaOberoi For your first question, yes, it should but if you are worried about it then test it yourself. For your second question, I have no idea as I have not seen the source code for that function; all I have to go on is the image you posted in the question but if it does return a comma-delimited `VARCHAR2` then it should work.

Comment: One last question - Can I use multiple SELECT INTO statements after BEGIN one below the other if I had to use multiple variables?

Comment: @ReeyaOberoi Yes, or you can use `SELECT col1, col2, col3 INTO variable1, variable2, variable3 FROM table_name WHERE ...` and select multiple variables in one statement.

Comment: I will need to use multiple `SELECT INTO` as my `WHERE` condition is different for populating each of the `variable1, variable2, variable3` . I tried to find questions on stackoverflow which contained multiple `SELECT INTO` statements inside a trigger but could not find any. Thank you for answering my question.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have your tables so I'll try to illustrate it using my own code.

This is what you're doing now: to us (humans), it is obvious that `L_NEW_ID` (its value is `10`) is contained in `L_VAR1` (its value is `'10,20'`). However, Oracle doesn't recognize that and returns "Not OK":

```
SQL> declare
  2    -- does L_NEW_ID exist in L_VAR1 and L_VAR2 (using your code)?
  3    l_new_id number := 10;
  4    --
  5    l_var1 varchar2(20) := '10,20';
  6    l_var2 varchar2(20) := '30,40';
  7  begin
  8    if l_new_id in (l_var1, l_var2) then
  9       dbms_output.put_line('OK');
 10    else
 11       dbms_output.put_line('Not OK');
 12    end if;
 13  end;
 14  /
Not OK

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL>
```

---

So, what to do? One option is to split variables to rows and then check whether search value (`10`, right?) exists in such a list of values (rows). The result is - as you can see - "OK":

```
SQL> declare
  2    l_new_id number := 10;
  3    --
  4    l_var1 varchar2(20) := '10,20';
  5    l_var2 varchar2(20) := '30,40';
  6    l_cnt  number;
  7  begin
  8    -- count how many times L_NEW_ID exists in L_VAR1 nad L_VAR2
  9    select count(*)
 10    into l_cnt
 11    from (-- split L_VAR1 into rows
 12          select regexp_substr(l_var1, '[^,]+', 1, level) val
 13            from dual
 14            connect by level <= regexp_count(l_var1, ',') + 1
 15          union all
 16          -- split L_VAR2 into rows
 17          select regexp_substr(l_var2, '[^,]+', 1, level)
 18            from dual
 19            connect by level <= regexp_count(l_var2, ',') + 1
 20         ) x
 21    where x.val = l_new_id;
 22
 23    if l_cnt > 0 then
 24       dbms_output.put_line('OK');
 25    else
 26       dbms_output.put_line('Not OK');
 27    end if;
 28  end;
 29  /
OK

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL>
```

Just to verify it, let's change `L_NEW_ID` value to e.g. `99` and see what happens; as expected, "Not OK" as `99` isn't contained in `10, 20` nor `30, 40`.

```
SQL> l2
  2*   l_new_id number := 10;
SQL> c/10/99
  2*   l_new_id number := 99;
SQL> /
Not OK

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL>
```